# Booting from a USB created with .IMG from QEMU

Tags: ubuntu, usb, live-usb

I create a virtual machine in QEMU and install Ubuntu Server.

Then I write the .IMG disk onto a SSD with `dd`, and it works.

But when I write the .IMG onto a thumb (flash) drive, the boot menu does not see it.

Is booting from a thumb drive any different from booting from SSD

Comment: It shouldn't be any different with a modern hardware. Do you verify that your BIOS is correctly configured to boot from USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved: the `dd` command:

```
dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb bs=16M
```

needs a sync afterwards:

```
sync
```

Or some syncing flags built into `dd` can be used. `dd` does not wait for buffered data to be actually written to the disk, by default.